# Hello, how can I remove all marks, and receive only emails - with emdeitor

Tags: regex, text-editors

how can I remove all marks, and receive only emails - with emdeitor
exmple

---

***exmple :***

'justin@inmovement.org');
'shaunness@hotmail.com');
'migmelgom@hotmail.com');

---

**I need result like this**

justin@inmovement.org
shaunness@hotmail.com
migmelgom@hotmail.com

---

Answer (score 0):

Try the followin:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace window.
- In the Find box, enter `[');]`
- Replace with: Leave empty
- Select Regular expression

[image: EMEditor - Replace window]

Comment: thank you, kinkg (_:

Comment: @1506 You can accept the answer if it has solved your issue. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).